# Docker Registry Stays Pending After Deployment

Tags: openshift-enterprise

I have installed OpenShift Enterprise as per the online guide (quick installation) but I'm stuck at deploying the registry.

[https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/install/docker_registry.html#deploy-registry][1]

I create the registry

```
oadm registry --config=/etc/openshift/master/admin.kubeconfig \
    --credentials=/etc/openshift/master/openshift-registry.kubeconfig \
    --images='registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-${component}:${version}'
```

I check that it was configured

```
[justin@172 ~]$ oc get se docker-registry
NAME              LABELS                    SELECTOR                  IP(S)            PORT(S)
docker-registry   docker-registry=default   docker-registry=default   172.30.144.220   5000/TCP
```

But it never runs it stays pending

```
[justin@172 ~]$ oc get pods
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
docker-registry-1-deploy   0/1       Pending   0          2h
```

I try to get some more info

```
[justin@172 ~]$ oc logs docker-registry-1-deploy
[justin@172 ~]$
```

but the logs command returns nothing

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I am working with RedHat architects to resolve the problem. I'll post whatever answers we're able to come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had attempted an install with one node sharing the machine with the master.

My nodes looked like this:

```
[root@master ~]# oc get nodes
NAME                 LABELS                                      STATUS
master.mydomain.com   kubernetes.io/hostname=master.mydomain.com   Ready,SchedulingDisabled
```

Note: SchedulingDisabled

I ran this command:

```
oc describe pod docker-registry-1-deploy
```

And it gave the reason for not being deployed which was that there were no nodes to schedule a deployment on.  Just to get things going quickly I performed the install again added a node on another VM.

Then

```
[root@master ~]# oc get nodes
NAME                 LABELS                                      STATUS
master.mydomain.com   kubernetes.io/hostname=master.mydomain.com   Ready,SchedulingDisabled
node1.mydomain.com    kubernetes.io/hostname=node1.mydomain.com    Ready
```

and I managed to successfully deploy the registry.